# Switching Grand Company

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I am wondering about whether you can switch the grand company you have chosen or not. And if so how. I have chosen the Maelstrom and want to switch to the Order of the Twin Adder because their gear is a bit more optimized for my class (bard).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can switch Grand Companies once you have reached the rank of Second Lieutenant by talking to an NPC in your Grand Company headquarters.

Once you switch, you will no longer be able to use any existing Grand Company gear you have, and you'll start at the very beginning rank-wise for your new Grand Company. If you reach Second Lieutenant in your new Grand Company (and at least 30 days have passed since you last switched), you can switch again if you'd like. When you switch, your old rank and company seals are retained, but you can't use them for anything if you don't currently belong to that Grand Company.

Comment: *"When you switch, your old rank and company seals are retained"* - You mean your rank from the original GC *(which you switched away from but are now switching back to)*, or the rank from GC you originally switched to and are now switching away from?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft All of your GCs retain their ranks, even when you switch around between them. So if you're a Second Lieutenant Twin Adder, you'll always be a Second Lieutenant Twin Adder if/when you ever switch back to them. The same applies to your unspent company seals.